# Visual Studio won't detect my device

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015

Yes, yet again another question about connecting a device to Visual Studio... I know there are plenty of answers, but I couldn't make it work, hence this new topic.

---

So I got a Visual Studio Community 2015. 
I created a new Cordova Project, using Cordova 6.1.1
When I used the ripple emulator, everything works fine. (I got a error 404 about *favicon.ico* and *ripple.js*, but the application runs fine)

To test on Android device, I got a Galaxy Note 2 running on Android 4.4.2. Developper option is activated, as weel as "*enable USB degugging*". Moreover, I can access the phone using windows explorer just fine.

Problem is, when I set "*Debug*" mode and "*Android*" Platform, VS2015 doesn't list the device in the menu, I simply got "Device". And if I try to run it nevertheless, I got a popup saying "*deployment error, continue anyway ?*". If I click on "continue", I got an error popping : "*Failed to install apk to device: [ 9%] /data/local/tmp/android-debug.apk*"

Do you guys have any idea how to resolve this ?

By the way, in the sdk manager, I installed *Android SDK Tools 25.2.2*, *Android SDK Platform-tools 24.0.3*, *Android SDK Build-tools 24.0.3*, *Android 6.0 API* and *Google USB Driver*.

When trying to update the Note 2 driver on my computer, windows says it's already up to date. I even trined to uninstall/reinstall the Google USB Driver.

Comment: you can also do with adb driver, but without visual studio...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to debug it, and without pdaNet :

- First, I reinstalled VS2015, and made sure to check "Android NDK", which I don't think I checked the first time
- I made sure jdk AND jre are correctly installed, and with the same version (I had jre  1.7 and jdk 1.8)
- I made sure my phone's driver was up to date

Cleaning and generating the solution was then good, everything runs well !

Answer (score 0):

Install a driver for your phone :) 
currently i am using pdaNet to connect my phone for android dev. 
check it here -> http://pdanet.co/a/

just for you to know how to check if you have driver for your phone http://www.junefabrics.com/android/driver.php

Comment: So...
I installed PdaNet on my computer, and PdaNet+ on my phone. After a lot of updates, I was finaly abled to connect the phone to the computer.

Comment: Anyway...

I still have the exact same error message in Visual Studio. Does it count that it's a "commuity" version ?


I tried something else : I managed to create an apk, then copied this file on the "download" folder of the phone. When trying to run it, I got another error : "_An error occured when analysing the package_". I have absolutely no idea if this is linked to the previous error or not.

Comment: Another try : I downloaded the OEM driver followinf the steps [from this website](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/run-app-apache/)
eveytime I try to update the driver, I got a popup saying : "*driver is up to date... USB MTP*"

Comment: have you tried every instructions from https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/set_up_device_for_development/ that fits for your mobile?

if you installed vs2015 using their installer with so many to set-up (JDK, SDK, NDK + HAXM and VS2015), then you only need to add some items to set-up.

- **google usb driver** (from sdk manager which you already have)
- **pdaNet** for desktop (Guide - http://www.topnotchtablets.com/installADBdriver)

after installations, you're phone should now be detected by vs2015. Beside debug, you're device name should be there.

Comment: ***
[additional info, not related to the issue but will give issue for you sooner or later]

remove Android SDK Build-tools 24.0.3 and download the latest build tools for 23, 22, 21, 20 and 19. Because build tools 24 will give an error for you when you try to deploy it

Answer (score 0):

As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1361126/vs-dont-see-device, you just need to make sure your USB Debugging is actually enabled in your device. If not, enable it, then restart your device and your IDE. It worked for me.